# How to keep alive a service, after starting, until the application be closed or killed in Android?

Tags: java, android, service

I am developing android application, so I am starting a service with alarm:

```
public void scheduleLocationCheckerAlarm() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationCheckerReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, LocationCheckerReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, 600000, pIntent);
}
```

LocationCheckerReceiver:

```
public class LocationCheckerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, LocationNotificator.class);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class LocationNotificator extends Service {
public LocationNotificator() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d("Location checker", "Service running");
    //My code is here
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Location checker", "Service destroyed");
}
```

So I want this service to be checking for something every 1 minute and to be running all the time, even when the application is closed by the user.

Comment: The What's problem are you getting ?

Comment: Did you declared Service in Manifest ?

Comment: The service is killed when the application is closed
Android manifest:
<service
            android:name=".services.LocationNotificator"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false" />

Answer (score 1):

You must call `startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, buildForegroundNotification(filename));` in order to ensure that your service running continuously. Also, this will post a notification from your app to show the user about the service state. Please follow the [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)).
Here is the code :

```
public class LocationNotificator extends Service {
private static int FOREGROUND_ID=1338;
public LocationNotificator() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
Log.d("Location checker", "Service running");
//My code is here

startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID,
                buildForegroundNotification(filename));
stopForeground(true);
return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
Log.d("Location checker", "Service destroyed");
}
private Notification buildForegroundNotification(String filename) {
NotificationCompat.Builder b=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

b.setOngoing(true);

b.setContentTitle("Some Title")
 .setContentText("some File name")
 .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
 .setTicker("downloading");

return(b.build());
}
```

Comment: Seems like I dont understand you.
I called startForeground from  public int onStartCommand() on my service, but nothing happens.

Comment: I've edited my post. Please follow the code sample provided.

Comment: I just tried it and there's no difference ,the notification doesn't show for some reason

Comment: this service is not long running now. Can this service be long running ? if Yes please let me know how

Answer (score 0):

You need to read this first. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

In a nutshell, start your service as a foreground service so there's lesser chance of Android killing your service. As a foreground service, you need to display an on-going notification in the status bar.

There's no direct way of making sure your service is never killed by the Android system. A workaround is to send a broadcast in `onDestroy()` of your service, and have a `Receiver` in your Android application start the service upon receiving the broadcast.

By the way, it seems that your service is sending location updates periodically to your backend server. This might be better implemented using [Firebase Job Dispatcher library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) or [Evernote's Android-Job library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job).

Comment: My service is doing get requests to my backend server, thanks for the reply !